# Make an element optional/mandatory based on another element using xsd:assert

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, assert, option-type

I believe XSD 1.1 has asserts that allows conditional logic.

I have a schema like this:

```
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Type" type="xs:integer" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Comment" type="xs:string" />
```

I want the `Comment` section to be mandatory only if the `Type` is 0. If `Type` is anything else, I want the `Comment` element to be optional.

How do I achieve this using asserts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
test="not(Type=0 and not(Comment))"
```

Comment: Correct but reducible: `Comment or Type != 0`.

Comment: It's reducible, but not to that. I think `Comment or not(Type = 0)` would be correct, assuming we read "Type is anything else" to include the case where it is absent.

Comment: Ah, yes, I think you're right.    For example, when both `Comment` and `Type` are absent, `Comment or Type != 0` fails but `Comment or not(Type = 0)` succeeds, which is probably desired.

Comment: Can we apply the same concept for attributes?

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work. I'm guessing because the attribute has not been defined at the time of the check. It's an attribute of the same element. @MichaelKay

Comment: @Bouramas Your code was wrong. If you need help finding out where it was wrong, raise a new question.

Answer (score 2):

**Credit**: Michael Kay, George Boole, and Augustus De Morgan.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
           vc:minVersion="1.1">

  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Type" type="xs:integer" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Comment" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:assert test="Comment or not(Type = 0)"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```